# Access to related model field in django_filters

Tags: django, select, django-filter

I'm constructing Django-based 4-language website for a real estate agency. I'm using django-filter package to filter my objects (real estate properties) by certain parameters, such as type (house, apartment, etc.), city and some others.

My 'type' field is a foreign key for the model 'Type'. It uses ModelChoiceFilter to select all available types from the database, and redner them as a `select` element with options, which is and is displayed as a drop list with options, which is good so far.

```
class SalePropertyFilter(FilterSet):
    ...

    type = ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Type.objects.all(),
        empty_label=_("Any type"),
        label="",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        )
```

But for some reason the options are displayed as slug names of the types ('house', 'apartment', etc., see the attached picture). It is the 'slug' field of my foreign key model Type. Instead of this, I want to print 'name' field in the options. This field is translated (django-modeltranslation package), so that in English version one should see options 'House', 'Apartment'..., and in Spanish version - 'Casa', 'Apartamento', etc.

I tried modify this field in my PropertyFilter as using '__' symbol (type__name instead of type), but it doesn't seem to work.

Please, help me, I'm stuck!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem consisted of two parts: 1) select options are displayed as slug names, 2) the field labels are not translated.

The first problem was caused by my silly error. The method "**str**" returned self.slug, which was wrong. It was solved my rewriting this method:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"
```

For the second problem I didn't find a proper solution. The form is generated by the RangeFilter, which is called by PropertyFilter with and, in theory, should get context from is (from the queryset which is passed as a parameter). Instead of this, this RangeFilter is initialized when I start the server (runserver), without the context, without the queryset, with default language ('en'). When I open the "Properties list" web page, this filter is initialized second time, this time with the context (query and language), but, for some reason, the form is rendered by first instance of the filter. I cannot understand, why it happens.

The solution, which I found, is not very good, but it works. I suppressed field labels in my RangeFilter, and render the form manually.

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'properties:list' %}">
    <div id="div_id_city" class="mb-3"> 
        {{ propertyform.city }}
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_type" class="mb-3"> 
        {{ propertyform.type }}
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_price" class="mb-3">
    <p>{% translate "Price, €" %}</p>
        {{ propertyform.price }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <button class="search-button">{% translate "Search" %}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this form, I display translated labels manually `(<p>{% translate "Price, €" %}</p>)`. In the choice fields, the labels are not necessary, since in my PropertyFilter, which is context-aware, I set placeholders, which are translated: `self.filters['type'].field.empty_label = _("Any type")`.

In result, the entire filter form on the page displays translated (see picture). However, I still would like to know the proper solution for this issue, so, if anyone knows the more nice solution for the problem, let me know, please.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.db.models import Q
from django_filters import FilterSet

class SalePropertyFilter(FilterSet):
    type = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Type.objects.all(),
        empty_label=_("Any type"),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        label="",
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Get the current language code
        current_language = self.data.get('language_code') or self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE

        # Create the choices with translated names
        type_choices = [(type.id, type.translate_name(current_language)) for type in Type.objects.all()]
        type_choices.insert(0, ("", _("Any type")))
        self.filters['type'].field.choices = type_choices

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel  # Replace with the actual model name
```

Comment: Thanks, Mahammadhusain! I feel that is it working approach, but now the language activation line fails: Cannot resolve keyword 'name_None' into field. Choices are: id, name, name_en, name_es, name_ru, name_ua, order, property, slug, slug_name. On my website, the language variables are kept in the environment. I switch language by hyperlink         "i18n/", with help of 'django.conf.urls.i18n'.

Comment: Mahammadhusain, the rest of your code works, but not quite the way I want. I mean, 'to_field_name' passes the translated type names to option names, and I need it pass the type names to option values. Formerly my form filed looked like <option value="1">house</option> <option value="2">apartment</option>, Now it looks like <option value="Casa">house</option> <option value="Apartamento">apartment</option>, etc., and should be <option value="1">Casa</option> <option value="2">Apartamento</option>, etc.

Comment: check now answer  is updated

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. The field now looks like before:  <option value="1">house</option> <option value="2">apartment</option>. Also, perhaps it helps: we are talking about field values, not field names.

Comment: After your last update, I get an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'LANGUAGE_CODE'. I can get rig of it by removing or commenting the fragment "or self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE". But now i get another error: 'Type' object has no attribute 'translate_name', and I actually do not understand what attribute is it. Please, let's figure it out!

Comment: Mahammadhusain, I'm trying to make work your last edition of the code. The line where current_language is determined, doesn't work (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'LANGUAGE_CODE'). So, I try to hardcode it (current_language = 'es)'. Then I get error that the Type object has no attribute "translated_field", so I replace it with the hardcode "name_es". Now I get another error: TypeError: 
ModelChoiceIterator.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. This time I don't know how to solve it.